# Why Typescript does not respect expected argument type parameter in generic method?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

When writing this:

```
class AB<Initial, Current = Initial> {

    array: AB<unknown, unknown>[] = []

    push<Next extends any>(ab: AB<Current, Next>) : AB<Initial, Next> {
        this.array.push(ab)
        return this as AB<Initial, Next>;
    }
}

// therefore ab is AB<'a','b'> and
// AB<'a','b'>.push<Next = 'x'>(ab: <Current,Next>) should expect AB<'b','x'>
const ab = new AB<'a', 'b'>();

// Since ab is AB<Initial = 'a', Current = 'b'>,
// the following ab.push<Next>'s parameter should
// expect AB<Initial = 'b', Current = Next> and
// AB<'e', 'x'> should raise an error because 'e' is not 'b'
const ax = ab.push(new AB<'e', 'x'>);

// Since ax is AB<Intial = 'a', Current = 'x'>,
// the following ax.push<Next>'s parameter should
// expect AB<Initial = 'x', Current = Next> and
// AB<'f', 'z'> should raise an error because 'f' is not 'x'
const az = ax.push(new AB<'f', 'z'>);
```

I expect Typescript to raise an error because the argument does not respect the generic type constraint from the method.

I have played a lot with type constraints before but I can't find any reason for this specific case.

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCBCAeAkgOwJYBd1hAGmgGEBXAJ1IFNVNoBeaNLHEAPmgG8AoT6X6McmACeALjhJiqANaoA9gHdUBSTIWoWAbQC6daNu59oAB2IQAFogByFAB41bmKgBMYYVEJYAKMACMxCRBJyKkwCazsWAEpofyRGbFwwhzYuQ0NMM3QIADoBUmFsk3NvH0ieNN5KTDJUaAys-hgA+OYkiIBuct4AX05ezgB6AbqzCkoAM1lKfh9oBoCAcjAFvAWfBbY3J0HhxeXV9ZZC0wtwmnoFmw2SsUCySmo8M6joc1liECdoWyMKYBpFutVlcWJxgLJUBAaL5dKgKPJxIglitoGtrpFOjtoABldCoYAUGZzJpxDAJEC6ZEEIIPc6ow54LEZQmTEAgBR4gDmM2O5isyQWMCMAjAAFsKI5SK8zO9Plifn8AaSmLhKUCiPcQrpnvxUNshoiFhQUZcNtLZV98llCW5vuQptAfH8wKZCUaFsToHIaGiwRCofwbLpfLyzJ44QjFsaCKaopiDbj8Tag-NSeTKfsNcFqJSQYyDczoKz2fIuYHQ-yIoLjCLxZLzR99cMFf9ES1VRcrtTNTn6DqtljFuMTQAvM1vRvQK0QG21MakB1O4Aumeo4ee72oq5+yHQkfBmyh8Pww3DmNjuNAA)

Comment: That was a typo I have just fixed, thanks

Comment: You don't use the generic type parameters anywhere in the class. Therefore, there is no difference between `AB<"a", "b">` and `AB<"w", "x">` *structurally*.

Comment: Yes that is a toy example but the infered expected argument changes as expected without enforcing anything

Comment: When I use the params it works: https://tsplay.dev/mb3OEW

Comment: You're right thanks! I have to try it in the actual code it comes from, but what in the name of black magic is this `#$initial!: Initial;` :) ?

Comment: All you really need to do is use it in some way. It's just a private property with an odd name so I don't accidentally use it. The `!` is an assertion for the compiler that the property will have a value (even though it won't).

Comment: I get it my initial implementation of AB had a `doSomething(input: Initial) {
        return {} as Current;
    }` method so it was ok but I had to remove it for code review.

So it seems Typescript kind of "forgets" about your type param if it not used that right ?

Comment: It doesn't "forget". It just says they're the same because *structurally* they are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is basically the following:

```
class A<T> {}

const a: A<number> = new A<number>();
const b: A<string> = a; // not an error
```

Because `A` does not use `T` in its definition in any way, it's basically just `{}`. However, if you use `T`, then the story is a little different:

```
class A<T> { value!: T }

const a: A<number> = new A<number>();
const b: A<string> = a; // error, because the types of the value property are different
```

This is because TypeScript is **structurally** typed. It doesn't care what name it has or what type parameters are given. It only cares that the *structure* of the type is valid.

Therefore, the solution to your problem would be to use the type parameters in some way. I like using properties because it's the simplest way to change the structure based on a type parameter:

```
class AB<Initial, Current = Initial> {
  #$initial!: Initial;
  #$current!: Current;
```

Private properties prevent the consumer of this class from accidentally using them. The dollar sign prefix makes sure that these don't show up in autocomplete suggestions, and remind you that they are "special".

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-rvQcjgOA8XOoEUiGLohLt9I5cB7H43IgA)

---

The `!` is an assertion, saying that the property will have a definite value. Of course, at runtime, it won't, but the compiler will scream at you for it.

Comment: The original implementation used the param but I had to remove it for review without realizing what it was doing to the type params ;)
Now I know that typescript will tend to ignore them in this case because they don't imply any structural difference.

Many thanks again :)